# How to get search domain of local Chromebook and NS records of that domain for Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, google-chrome-os

I would like to get the search domain from chromeOS notebook and then NS records of the search domain using javascript for chrome app. The chromeapp will be running on chromeOS.

I am able to get the records using resolveNs method of NodeJs "dns" library but it needs nodeJS. And for that I need to package nodeJS with chrome App? I am new to chrome os.

I tried to browserify that but got several issues. Is there any way to get the search domain and all NS records of a domain using JavaScript?

Or is there a way to browserify the 'dns' module of NodeJS. In my try, browserify does the job but when I open the javascript in chrome, it says: `fs.readFile is not a function`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
    at Platform.parseResolv (bundle.js:4295)
    at Platform._populate (bundle.js:4248)
    at new Platform (bundle.js:4201)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:4409)
    at Object.require.18../utils (bundle.js:4411)
    at s (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3155)
    at Object.require.15../packet (bundle.js:3815)
    at s (bundle.js:1)
```

Same happens when I replace fs by browserify-fs. My code in nodeJS is (it works fine when I say `node filename.js`):

```
var dnsresolve = require('native-dns/lib/client').resolve;
  dnsresolve('xxx.pb1.lan', 'NS', function (err, addresses) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));
   });
```